# ERROR: Dependency "mount" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake Linux while trying to install glib-2.60.0

Tags: linux, cmake, glib

Runing the following command from a terminal:

```
sudo python3 meson _build
```

:

```
**The Meson build system**
Version: 0.50.0
....
Checking for function "ngettext" : YES
Checking for function "bind_textdomain_codeset" : YES
Dependency mount found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)   

meson.build:1807:2: ERROR: Dependency "mount" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake

A full log can be found at ~/glib-2.60.0/_build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

meson-log.txt error :

```
Checking for function "bind_textdomain_codeset" : YES
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'mount' with pkg-config executable '/usr/local/bin/pkg-config'
Called `/usr/local/bin/pkg-config --modversion mount` -> 1

CMake binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Dependency mount found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

meson.build:1807:2: ERROR: Dependency "mount" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

I searched for the 'mount.pc' file. But it seems like it does not exist. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I corrected an error like this on a CentOS box with: `yum install libmount-devel`

Comment: Tnx, now it works by installing   libmount-dev

Comment: Thanks fixed this error message as well: `meson.build:907:0: ERROR:  Native dependency 'mount' not found`

Comment: In case anyone needs it, the **Ubuntu** command is: `sudo apt-get install libmount-dev`

Comment: Thanks @GabrielFair for mentioning Ubuntu pkg.

Comment: what about alpine users?